# Check word frequency of imported file against vocabulary python

Tags: python, nltk

I want to create bag of words representation of text file in form of vector (.toarray()) . I am using code :

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(input="file")
f = open('D:\\test\\45.txt')
bag_of_words = vectorizer.fit_transform([f])
print(bag_of_words)
```

I want to use vocabulary of countvectorizer for comparison. I have text file which I tokenized and want to use it as vocabulary. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the tokenization was done by insert whitespaces between the single tokens creating an vocabulary from text is as simple as:

```
f = open('foo.txt')
text = f.read() # text is a string
tokens = text.split() # breaks the string in single tokens
vocab  = list(set(tokens)) # set() removes the doubles form the token list
```

Comment: and how to compare with another text?